VLAN routing on L3 switch, can't set IP address on SVI
I'm currently working on a project that requires connecting 2 different networks together to rout data between them. We have multiple physically separate networks, and I need to find a way to connect them together to allow inter-VLAN routing. I believe I understand most of the basics of setting up L3 routing on my switch, a Netgear GSM7228PS, but it seems that I'm missing something in practice.
Network setup:

Net 1 (our network): 192.168.0.0/16
Net 2 (the other network): 10.101.0.0/16
The switch is part of network 1. 192.168.5.166, netmask 255.255.0.0

I run into trouble when trying to set up SVIs for the routing. The other network gets a single port on our switch, set to VLAN 6. The SVI on that VLAN is 10.101.1.1, netmask 255.255.0.0. Our network is on VLAN 5. I'm trying to set up an SVI on that VLAN, 192.168.1.1, netmask 255.255.0.0. When I do this, I get the following error.
All routing interfaces, service ports and network ports must be configured on different subnets

I don't entirely understand what is conflicting here. It is my understanding that the SVI should be in our main subnet so that the devices on the network can reach the SVI to route to the other network, but that seems to be incorrect. If I put the SVI outside our subnet, as I did for the other network on VLAN 6, it is created properly, but then devices can't reach it. What am I missing here?
Does this have something to do with the switch's management interface being in the main subnet on VLAN 5? This is a fairly old switch, so could it be some kind of limitation of the hardware/firmware?
I hope that I'm being clear enough in my description here. Please let me know if any more information might help. Thanks in advance for any help with this.


Does this have something to do with the switch's management interface being in the main subnet on VLAN 5?

Yes. 192.168.5.166/16 and 192.168.1.1/16 are on the same subnet. You need to either use addresses from different subnets or reduce the subnet sizes (lengthen netmasks) to separate the interfaces.
